# Can adhoc deployment be used to test in a sandbox environment for In-App-Purchase?

Tags: ios, testing, ad-hoc-distribution, in-app-purchase

I want to test my IAP in a development ( sandbox ) environment.

But my XCode SDK 's version is lower that it can't identify my development device as green mark in XCode.

So every time if I want to test my App in my Development device, I have to first deploy my test App by adhoc deployment to my Development device.
Then test it on Wi-Fi if internet online needed.

Can I use adhoc deployment to test IAP function in my development device via Wi-Fi this way?

because I already have 2 versions of XCode on my Dev. machine, so I don't want to update my XCode to new versions  in the near future in case something wrong unexpected happend.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: yes. In-App-Purchase api will automatically work with sandbox environment until application successfully reviewed by Apple. Of-course, you need create test users via itunes connect to test it. Check the [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH1-SW1)
.